# laravel9: how to get full route name

Tags: laravel-9

i have this from my `routes/web.php`

```php
Route::group([
    'middleware'    => 'user',
    'prefix'    => 'currency',
    'as'        => 'currency-'
], function (){
    Route::get('/', [CurrencyController::class, 'index'])->name('currency');
    Route::get('add', [CurrencyController::class, 'add'])->name('add');
    Route::get('edit/{id}', [CurrencyController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');

    Route::post('add', [CurrencyController::class, 'form_add']);
});
```

i need to get the route with format the prefix name and the route name. So the result will be like `currency-currency` and `currency-add`.
can i do something like `Route::PrefixRoute()`?

Answer (score 1):

you can access current request route name using one of the below methods.

```
public function index(Request $request){
       
  dd($request->route()->getName());
}
```

or

```
request()->route()->getName()
```

or

import use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;` so you can access like

```
Route::currentRouteName()
```